# Exception being handled in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, master-pages

If an exception was thrown in a page, would it be possible to be handled within the masterpage (assuming it wasn't handled before?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method on the master page is one in the call chain above where the exception occurs, it can be caught in it.

What are you trying to accomplish? At a guess I would say that you need to explore the creation of a base page where you have your exception handling and inherit your other pages from it.

Comment: Well I was hoping I could catch all exceptions that were unhandled on a page and show a message on the masterpage to the user

Comment: @m.edmondson - do you mean you want to _display_ the errors on the master page?

Comment: No not the actual errors - just a generic message whilst e-mailing me the stacktrace etc

Comment: @m.edmondson - Here is a good article that goes into master pages in depth. I feel you have some misconceptions about how they work. http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could add handler to `Page.Error` event:

```
protected void Master_Init() 
{
    Page.Error += MyErrorHandler;
}
```

I am not sure, that there is `Master_Init` method in MasterPage class, but I believe, you got an idea.